# Mocking constructor call in Justmock fails for UrlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, justmock

In justmock we can return mocked instances instead of actual instances by Arranging the constructor call like

```
Mock.Arragne(()=>new MyClass(Arg.IsAny<string>())).IgnoreInstance().Returns(Mock.Create<MyClass>());
```

but when I tried the same with `UrlHelper` class, instead of mocked type, actual type is getting instantiated. Can anybody tell if there's any mistake in this:

UrlModel class

```
    public class UrlModel
    {
        private UrlHelper url;
        public UrlModel()
        {
           url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        }
    }
```

Test method :

```
public void UrlTest()
{
   Mock.Arrange(() => HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Returns(Mock.Create<RequestContext>());

    var mockedUrl = Mock.Create<UrlHelper>();

    Mock.Arrange(() => new UrlHelper(Arg.IsAny<RequestContext>()))
        .IgnoreArguments()
        .IgnoreInstance()
        .Returns(mockedUrl);

    //Here url will have actual instance instead of mocked instance
    var model = new UrlModel();

    //Assert is ommitted for bravity .. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Typemock](https://www.typemock.com/) to test your code without adding any new interfaces, by faking `RequestContext` and modifying the property behavior:

```
[TestMethod,Isolated]
public void UrlTest()
{
    //Arrange 
    var fakeRequest = Isolate.Fake.Instance<RequestContext>();
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).WillReturn(fakeRequest);

    //Act
    var res = new UrlModel();
    //getting the private field so it can be asserted
    var privateField = Isolate.NonPublic.InstanceField(res, "url").Value as UrlHelper;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(fakeRequest, privateField.RequestContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manually instantiating an instance of `UrlHelper` in the constructor of `UrlModel`. `UrlModel` is now tightly coupled to `UrlHelper` (*new is glue*). Make an dependency abstraction that you can allow for a more loosely coupled model and improved mock-ability

```
public interface IUrlHelperAccessor {
    UrlHelper UrlHelper { get; }
}
```

and inject that into the `UrlModel`

```
public class UrlModel {
    private UrlHelper url;
    public UrlModel(IUrlHelperAccessor accessor) {
       url = accessor.UrlHelper;
    }
    //...other code
}
```

Now you arrange the test accordingly

```
public void UrlTest() {
    Mock.Arrange(() => HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext)
        .Returns(Mock.Create<RequestContext>());

    var mockedUrl = Mock.Create<UrlHelper>(Constructor.Mock);
    var mockedAccessor = Mock.Create<IUrlHelperAccessor>();

    Mock.Arrange(() => mockedAccessor.UrlHelper).Returns(mockedUrl);

    //Here url will have actual instance instead of mocked instance
    var model = new UrlModel(mockedAccessor);

    //Assert is omitted for brevity .. 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why the constructor mocking in this case would not have worked is that the `UrlModel` class has been part of a test class - code in test classes is not itself mockable.

The other thing that comes to mind is that you might have been misled by the debugger. When you create a mock of a non-abstract type with the profiler running, the instance itself is of the same type as the mocked type - it's not a derived type, say, `UrlHelperMock`, as is the case when the profiler is not running. Can you confirm using the debuggers `Make Object ID` function that the mock instance and the instance returned from `new` are really not the same?

Did you come to the conclusion that the `new` expression mocking did not work, because your arrangements of `UrlHelper` did not work, or was it something else?